# Missing spaces and dot in election Text

Tags: bug, status-completed

Just a minor correction. On the 3. [SO election tab](https://stackoverflow.com/election/5?tab=election) I see:

> This election is currently in the primary phase.The election phase
>   begins in 3 daysYou must have more than 150 reputation to vote in the
>   primary for this election.

I thing it should be `phase. The` and `days. You`

Comment: or a `<br />` instead of `\r\n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for posting the bug.

This is fixed and will be seen in rev 2014.2.18.1377.